# C Program not running

Tags: c

I wrote a code to check if a number is deficient which runs just fine in C. Then I tried to modify the code to print deficient numbers within a range, it compiled successfully but It always crashes at runtime, here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int num,c=0,i,k,b;
int t_factors;
int range;
int factors[50];

printf("Enter the total number of figures you want to check \n");
scanf("%d",&range);
for(num=1;num<=range;num++)
{
for(i;i<=num;i++)
{
    if (num%i==0)
    {
        factors[i]=i;
        t_factors++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("");
    }
    }
    for(k;k<=t_factors;k++)
    {
        c=c+factors[k];
    }
    b=2*num;
    if (c<b)
    printf("%d is deficient \n",num);
    else
    printf("%d is not deficient \n",num);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: You need to set `c` to zero before analyzing each value in the range too; setting it to zero once isn't sufficient. You're going to have very few deficient numbers after a while — once you sort out your other problems. `k` too is not initialized.  Why you'd write `for (i; i <= num; i++)` is beyond me — you'd do best with `for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)`, and similarly with `for (k = 0; k <= t_factors; k++)`,  The `printf("")` call is peculiar too; it does nothing. The lines `factors[i]=i; t_factors++;` is bogus too; you probably need `factors[t_factors++] = i;` (and you must zero `t_factors`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't make sure your variables are properly initialized — `i`, `c`, `k`, `t_factors`.  You also don't load the array `factors` correctly.  A basic set of changes to your code (using the C99 'define a variable almost anywhere' feature) yields:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int range;

    printf("Enter the total number of figures you want to check: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &range) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (int num = 1; num <= range; num++)
    {
        int t_factors = 0;
        int factors[50];
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
                factors[t_factors++] = i;
        }
        int c = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < t_factors; k++)
            c = c + factors[k];
        int b = 2 * num;
        if (c < b)
            printf("%d is deficient\n", num);
        else
            printf("%d is not deficient\n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you type 30 as the response, this produces:

```
Enter the total number of figures you want to check: 30
1 is deficient
2 is deficient
3 is deficient
4 is deficient
5 is deficient
6 is not deficient
7 is deficient
8 is deficient
9 is deficient
10 is deficient
11 is deficient
12 is not deficient
13 is deficient
14 is deficient
15 is deficient
16 is deficient
17 is deficient
18 is not deficient
19 is deficient
20 is not deficient
21 is deficient
22 is deficient
23 is deficient
24 is not deficient
25 is deficient
26 is deficient
27 is deficient
28 is not deficient
29 is deficient
30 is not deficient
```

You can streamline that a bit by avoiding the array of factors and accumulating the terms as you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int range;

    printf("Enter the total number of figures you want to check: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &range) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (int num = 1; num <= range; num++)
    {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
                s += i;
        }
        if (s < 2 * num)
            printf("%d is deficient\n", num);
        else
            printf("%d is not deficient\n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It produces the same output as the first program, which is encouraging.  You'd keep the factors array if you wanted to print out data to justify the determination of 'deficient' vs 'not deficient', but while you're not doing anything more than adding up the elements in the array after finding the factors, you really don't need it.

You could look at [Numbers — abundant, deficient, perfect and amicable](https://www.encyclopedia.com/education/news-wires-white-papers-and-books/numbers-abundant-deficient-perfect-and-amicable) and see that you don't need to include `num` in the checked factors and you don't need the `2 * num`, and you can 'optimize' by not checking the numbers larger than `num / 2` since they're not factors, yielding:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int range;

    printf("Enter the total number of figures you want to check: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &range) != 1)
        return 1;

    for (int num = 1; num <= range; num++)
    {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num / 2; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
                s += i;
        }
        if (s < num)
            printf("%d is deficient\n", num);
        else if (s > num)
            printf("%d is abundant\n", num);
        else
            printf("%d is perfect\n", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output from that is:

```
Enter the total number of figures you want to check: 30
1 is deficient
2 is deficient
3 is deficient
4 is deficient
5 is deficient
6 is perfect
7 is deficient
8 is deficient
9 is deficient
10 is deficient
11 is deficient
12 is abundant
13 is deficient
14 is deficient
15 is deficient
16 is deficient
17 is deficient
18 is abundant
19 is deficient
20 is abundant
21 is deficient
22 is deficient
23 is deficient
24 is abundant
25 is deficient
26 is deficient
27 is deficient
28 is perfect
29 is deficient
30 is abundant
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, got what I'm looking for and thanks for the additional codes too. But I'm curious, why do we have to use an if statement on the range?

Comment: If you mean “why test the result of `scanf()`?”, then it is because you won’t know whether the input was successful without the check. There’s an argument that the value that was read should be validated too, reporting negative or zero values, and maybe limiting the range to 1,000 or 1,000,000.  Checking that the input succeeded is merely the simplest and most crucial check.  The code could be modified to take command line arguments, too.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably the cause of your problem is that the `i` variable is not initialized and when you do `num % i` is not certain what happens.

Comment: That's one uninitalized variable.  There's also `c`, `k`, and `t_factors` to worry about too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's right, but the case I mentioned is the first that happens hence it answers the question. From that one, is easy to deduce for the OP that also the other variables should be initialized.